# flying sailing drone

Tags: diagrams

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw plot [hobby] coordinates {(0,4) (1,3.2) (2,1.5) (2.5,1.2) (3,1) (4,0.8)};
\end{tikzpicture}





\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, thick] (-1,1) -- (1,-1);
\draw[black, thick] (-1,-1) -- (1,1);
\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) ;
\draw[black, thick] (0,0) -- (0,-1.5);
\draw[black, thick] (0,-1.5) -- (0.5,-1);
\draw[black, thick] (0,-1.5) -- (-0.5,-2);
\filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](-1,1) circle (.3);
\filldraw[color=red!60, fill=white, very thick](-1,-1) circle (.3);
\filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](1,-1) circle (.3);
\filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](1,1) circle (.3);
\draw (-.5,-2) .. controls (0.1,-2.8) and (.3,-2) .. (.5,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I have done this, but don't know how to put it on path.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately this is not a "please do this for me" site. Show us what you've done so far with a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors. Then tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: @SandyG yes, I added things I tried.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I just added it, I need to put it on a path and add water.

Comment: You should put the original hand-drawn image in the question also so we can see what you want.

Comment: @SandyG hand-drawn image exists in the question.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using `pic`, which is like a mini `tikzpicture` you can use on a path. In the code below, I took your drone code and turned it into a `pic`. The origin of your code determines where the `pic` is placed, so I shifted the placement using `yshift` (and also scaled it). Then you can place it on a path just like you would any node.

For fun I made a random river using `decorations.pathmorphing`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{drone/.pic={
    \draw[black, thick] (-1,1) -- (1,-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (-1,-1) -- (1,1);
    \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) ;
    \draw[black, thick] (0,0) -- (0,-1.5);
    \draw[black, thick] (0,-1.5) -- (0.5,-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (0,-1.5) -- (-0.5,-2);
    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](-1,1) circle (.3);
    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=white, very thick](-1,-1) circle (.3);
    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](1,-1) circle (.3);
    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](1,1) circle (.3);
    \draw (-.5,-2) .. controls (0.1,-2.8) and (.3,-2) .. (.5,-1);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every pic/.style={yshift=1cm, scale=.5, transform shape}]
  \pgfmathsetseed{1415}
  \draw[decorate, decoration={random steps, segment length=3mm, amplitude=1pt}, line width=8mm, cyan!60!white](-.5,-.4)--(9,-.4);
  \draw[<->, thick](0,1.5)node[left]{$z$}|-(1.5,0)node[below]{$x$};
  \draw(0,4)to[out=-20, in=180]pic[pos=0]{drone}pic[pos=1]{drone}(5,0)pic[xshift=3cm]{drone};
  \draw[<->, thick, red](0,-1)--node[below]{flying}(5,-1);
  \draw[<->, thick, red](5,-1)--node[below]{sailing}(9,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```